# Viscosity solution converging to conservation law solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, viscosity-solutions

I am studying conservation laws, particularly the Burger's equation and I am dealing with the proposition that states that the solutions of the Burger's equation with viscosity converges to a solution (weak) of the conservation law (unviscous).

Well, when we do the integration by parts to transpose the derivatives to the test function $\phi$, because of the viscosity $\epsilon u^\epsilon_{xx}$ term, we must do $\phi_{xx}$ . This means, I must have $\phi\in C_0^2$ (twice derivative).

So, we do all the calculus and by end the integration with the term $\phi_{xx}$ will be lost (because $\epsilon\rightarrow 0 $).

My doubt is this: 
At the proof that the limit is solution of the conservation law we use $\phi \in C_0^2$ and prove that the integrals are valid for THESE test functions. But the integrals must be valid for all $\phi \in C_0^1$ functions...

Thanks.

========

***Edit***

$u^\epsilon_t+f(u^\epsilon)_x=\epsilon u^\epsilon_{xx}\qquad (i)$

Let be $\phi$ a test function with $\phi(x,t)=0$ if $x\not\in (a,b)$ or $t\geq T$ (*). Define $\phi_0(x):=\phi (x,0)$ and $u_0^\epsilon(x):=u^\epsilon(x,0)$.

Integrating $(i)$:
$\int_a^b\int_0^T u^\epsilon_t\phi dtdx+\int_0^T \int_a^b f(u^\epsilon)_x\phi dxdt=\epsilon\int_a^b\int_0^T u^\epsilon_{xx}\phi dtdx\qquad (ii)$

Integrating by parts at left member and doing the cancels from (*):
$-\int_a^b\int_0^T [u^\epsilon\phi_t +f(u^\epsilon)\phi_x] dtdx+\int_a^b u^\epsilon_0\phi_0 dx=\epsilon\int_a^b\int_0^T u^\epsilon_{xx}\phi dxdt\qquad (iii)$

Integrating by parts at right member and doing the cancels from (*):
$-\int_a^b\int_0^T [u^\epsilon\phi_t +f(u^\epsilon)\phi_x] dtdx+\int_a^b u^\epsilon_0\phi_0 dx=-\epsilon\int_0^T\int_a^b u^\epsilon_{x}\phi_x dxdt\qquad (iv)$

So, at paper I am studying, the autor derives one more time at the right member, considering $\phi \in C_0^2$. Once I have to prove for any $\phi \in C_0^1$ by definition of weak solution, I have this doubt.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier if you include the equality where you have problem doing the integration by part.

Comment: Can you show what you get after one integration by parts?  One way to make progress is to show that the result after transposing one derivative simplifies.  Then you don't integrate again and you don't need a second derivative of the test function.

Comment: @ArcticChar, please, could you look the post again? I've edited. Thank you very much.

Comment: @EricTowers , please, could you look the post again? I've edited. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation (iv) obviously does not hold for test functions in $C^1_0$ because these don't have second derivatives . But once you take the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$, an identity results that requires only $\phi \in C_0^1$. And you have proved it for all $\phi \in C_0^2$. Therefore you can now obtain it also for all $\phi \in C_0^1$ by approximation.

The main issue is to show that $u^\epsilon$ converges to some function $u$ **and** that  $f(u^\epsilon)$ converges to $f(u)$, in some suitable sense. That is done with entropy conditions (e.g.).

Comment: Really... I can get the approximations of the functions of $C^1_0$ by functions of $C^2_0$... Thank you so much. Yes, I need to study these main issue yet. Thanks.